# how to solve the redefinition error in c++

Tags: c++, header, g++, redefinition

For some reason when i run a c++ program with special characters they are not displayed as they should, so i made this header file:

```
#ifndef Tildes_h
#define Tildes_h

unsigned char a_con_tilde = 160;
unsigned char a_may_con_tilde = 181;
unsigned char e_con_tilde = 130;
unsigned char e_may_con_tilde = 144;
unsigned char i_con_tilde = 161;
unsigned char i_may_con_tilde = 214;
unsigned char o_con_tilde = 162;
unsigned char o_may_con_tilde = 224;
unsigned char u_con_tilde = 163;
unsigned char u_may_con_tilde = 233;
unsigned char enie =164;
unsigned char enie_may =165;
unsigned char u_con_dieresis = 129;
unsigned char u_may_con_dieresis = 154;
unsigned char numero = 167;

#endif
```

it works correctly when i use it in one cpp file:

//  invertebrado.cpp

```
#include "animal.h" // base class
#include "terrestre.h" //derived class
#include "invertebrado.h" //the derived class im working on
#include "tildes.h" // the problematic header
```

but i get the redefinition error when i use the header in another cpp file simultaneously:

//  vertebrado.cpp

```
#include "animal.h" //base class
#include "terrestre.h" //derived class
#include "vertebrado.h" //other derived class im working on
#include "tildes.h" //the problematic header
```

multiple definition....... first defined here

i ve tried moving the header to the parent classes files but it still doesnt work

Comment: What's the exact error you've got? Are you sure it concerns tildes.h?

Comment: absolutely. It says  multiple definition of a_con_tilde ...

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce this...

Comment: Please read the linked questions. While I have no idea why as I didn't close it, the linked questions seem to be the reason this is failing.

Comment: it's ok. I know you didnt , it was a "moderator" who did it

Comment: Again, please read the linked questions.